# Get the Value of WPF Listview rows and compare them with database field using Linq query

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

i want to compare ECH_INTITULE in my database with the values of the listview rows but my problem is that i can't access the Listview items in my Linq query

here is my Xaml code for my Listview :

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="query" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="430" Margin="24,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="940" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView x:Name="gridView">
                <GridViewColumn Header="Fournisseur" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding fournisseur}" Width="280"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header ="Adresse Mail" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding email}" Width="270"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header ="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding date}" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Fichier CSV" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding xxx}" Width="105"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Fichier PDF" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding xxx}" Width="105"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

and here is my c# code :

```
//Generate CSV Files for each item in the Listview
        CsvFileDescription outpCsvFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
        {
            SeparatorChar = ',',
            FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            var infoEcheances = from f in db.F_ECHEANCES
                                //where f.ECH_Intitule == ???
                                select new { f.ECH_Intitule, f.ECH_DateEch, f.CG_Num, f.ECH_Piece, f.ECH_RefPiece, f.ECH_Montant, f.ECH_Libelle };


            CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
            string myPath = @"C:\Users\DefaultAccount\Desktop\Projet Top Of Travel\FichiersCSV\";
            string filename = string.Format("Facture{0}.csv", i);
            string finalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(myPath, filename);
            cc.Write(infoEcheances, finalPath, outpCsvFileDescription);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly compare a row like that. 
Please try with below code.

```
//Generate CSV Files for each item in the Listview
    CsvFileDescription outpCsvFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
    {
        SeparatorChar = ',',
        FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < listView.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        var infoEcheances = from f in db.F_ECHEANCES
                            where f.ECH_Intitule == listView.Items[i].f.ECH_Intitule
                            select new { f.ECH_Intitule, f.ECH_DateEch, f.CG_Num, f.ECH_Piece, f.ECH_RefPiece, f.ECH_Montant, f.ECH_Libelle };


        CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
        string myPath = @"C:\Users\DefaultAccount\Desktop\Projet Top Of Travel\FichiersCSV\";
        string filename = string.Format("Facture{0}.csv", i);
        string finalPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(myPath, filename);
        cc.Write(infoEcheances, finalPath, outpCsvFileDescription);
    }
```

Comment: i have got an error of : object does not contain a definition of f. so it does not accept the argument ECH_INTITULE in :  listview,Items[1].f.ECH_INTITULE

Comment: That I gave as a sample. You have to replace it with your item name as per your requirement